# MainWindow.ShowDialogue() in a WPF library

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm accustomed to Winforms where you can create a window and display it via:

`Window.ShowDialogue();`

I'm using the default `MainWindow.xaml` in a class library project.  I had to delete the App.xaml file to complete the conversion.  I want to launch the main window in a simple test.  E.G.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RunPd()
    {            
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.ShowDialogue();
    }
```

Show/ShowDialogue() is not available.  All I have is

`GetChildren<>, GetParents<>, InitializeComponent and LoadTree<>.`

How can I display MainWindow.xaml?

UPDATE

Main window code:

`public partial class MainWindow : Window`

Comment: Can you please clarify.  In xaml MainWindow should be inherited from System.Windows.Window which has the method you want  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx)

Comment: Why not just create a basic App.xaml with StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"  ?   Is there a reason to not have an App.xaml?

Comment: The class library wouldn't compile when I had App.xaml. I don't recall the specific errors, but the solution on another SO post was to delete App.xaml.

Comment: OK, a Class Libray project is not intended to have a UI (MainWindow.xaml).  Why did you not just create a WPF Application?

Comment: POst your XAML + full C# code behind

Comment: Does your test run in the same project? if not, does your project have references to WindowsBase.dll, PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll? these are the core WPF libraries that define most WPF classes.

Comment: @Blam it shouldn't be a problem to have WPF controls (XAML + code behind) defined in a class library. I think he might have a reference problem.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail. A lot of what you mention doesn't make much sense, such as having MainWindow.xaml in a "library" and deleting App.Xaml. AFAIK WPF windows can only be used in WPF applications, you can't just open one from a .Net assembly.

If you go to Definition on the `GetChildren` method, what assembly/namespace does it take you to? WPF windows do have `Show` and `ShowDialog` methods which are part of the `System.Windows.Window` class within the `PresentationFramework` assembly.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey your class library won't build if you have app.xaml because app.xaml has its `Build Action` set to `ApplicationDefinition` or something like that by default, which is not allowed in class libraries.

Comment: @StevePy not true. I have thousands of class libraries that contain all sorts of WPF objects from windows to usercontrols to XAML only styles and dictionaries.

Comment: @HighCore - WPF Controls, yes. WPF Forms, I don't believe so. Especially attempting to open one without a WPF Application defined. (Deleted App.xaml)

Comment: @StevePy pff.. you have no idea what you're talking about. There's no such thing as a 'form' in WPF. and I do have Windows defined in class libraries (which are then open by an application, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll, System.Xaml, PrentationationCore and PrentationFramework.  Once I added these references the unit test worked.

Curious as to why I did not need to add these assemblies in Winforms...?

Comment: because winforms sucks. It doesn't have half the classes WPF has. that's why the whole winforms thing fits in a single assembly System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Ok highcore is a bit ruff but he's right, it will be in your best interest NOT to think of xaml as winforms, just like you dont think HTML is winforms.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ShowDialog()`

```
  public void RunPd()
  {
      MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
      window.ShowDialog();
  }
```

Comment: sa_ddam213 is right but I am confused about deleting the app.xaml - I have created lots and lots of XAML applications using prism/MVVM light/no framework etc and never had to do this. I assume you added a Main method to your program as well. It won't even build without one when you remove the app.xaml file. I would love to see this post about about removing the app.xaml, I suspect that you are treating the symptom not the problem.

Comment: Well `App.xaml` is basically the winforms version of `Program.cs`, I don't think removing it is a good idea as you now have no entry point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could be the issue or not (your question is a bit vague); however, right-click on the xaml file in the VisualStudio project and click on Properties.  Then make sure that "Build Action" is set to "Page."

If this is already set, please make a comment as to that as well.